# Como definir nos parâmetros o tipo de argumentos que devem ser enviados?

Tags: python, tipagem

Exemplo tosco do que eu quero (que não funciona):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def a(int(b), str(c)): # Isso não funciona, mas quero algo assim.
    print('Isso é um Numero: %i' %b)
    print('Isso eh uma String: %s' %c)

a(10, 'Texto')



# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Não Quero fazer isso.
def a(b, c):
    # Não Quero fazer isso.
    if not ('int' in str(type(b))): return False
    if not ('str' in str(type(c))): return False

    print('Isso é um Numero: %i' %b)
    print('Isso eh uma String: %s' %c)

a(10, 'Texto')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algo assim?

```
def a(b : int, c : str):
    print('Isso é um Numero: %i' %b)
    print('Isso eh uma String: %s' %c)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/HintParameter.py).

[É possível desde Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) e está melhorando o suporte, o que culminará no 4.0 sendo uma linguagem com suporte "total" à tipagem de variáveis, incluindo aí parâmetros, membros e elementos de estruturas. Ainda não será uma linguagem de tipagem estática, pense como alguns testes de unidade inseridos automaticamente para você e que o compilador terá tratamento especial. Ainda haverá falhas, performance ruim e outros problemas da tipagem dinâmica, mas já é uma ganho considerável.

Note que não é algo de uso normal, é preciso usar uma biblioteca, conforme mostra a documentação. Se quiser saber mais tem a [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

As linguagens de tipagem dinâmica *mainstream* estão indo por esse caminho de um modo ou de outro. Só não digo que perceberam que foi um erro terem adotado a tipagem dinâmica que não escala bem, porque estavam certos na época, uma linguagem de *script* deve ter essa tipagem mesmo. O problema é agora que essas linguagens conseguiram público, e esse público não quer largar sua linguagem prefira e ir para uma que lhe atende melhor nas novas demandas que não são *scripts*, aí a linguagem resolve ser o que ela nunca foi para atender essas pessoas e continuar com o sucesso.

Comment: kudos pela anotação de tipo, isso deveria ser mais promovido!